# Does $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx < \infty$ imply that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx < \infty$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

My intuitive guess is that it does because if an integral is infinite on some range, then we can't just cancel out that infinity with another infinity, because $\infty - \infty$ is undefined.

Therefore, if for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(x)dx \text{ is undefined }$, then also, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx \text{ is undefined}$, and the contrapositive of this is the statement in question.

Obviously this is an extremely hand-wavey argument, and hence the post. Thanks!

Extra question: if the implication in the title is indeed true and I want to state it, but $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx < \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$, how would I briefly justify it in a sentence or so, without explicitly proving it?

Edit: Someone posted a comment (which they've now seemingly deleted) mentioning that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x)dx + \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx + \int_{b}^{\infty}f(x)dx.$$

Now, let us consider the function $f(x) = x$, and let $a = -b$ with $a \leq b$. Then can we argue that $\int_{-\infty}^{-b}x dx = - \int_{b}^{\infty}x dx$, and hence the two cancel, giving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xdx  = \int_{-b}^{b}xdx < \infty$, but $\int_{-\infty}^{-b}x dx$ diverges.

But also the value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xdx$ depends on the choice of $b$ and hence the integral is undefined...?

When writing the title, I treated "$< \infty$" as meaning defined, which now seems wrong. In light of this, if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is defined, does that imply that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ is defined for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$?

Comment: EDIT: It seems the person I was responding to removed their comment; they said that I can't define $f(x) = x$ because its integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ diverges and hence violates the condition in the title. My response follows: the argument in the edit is independent of that assumption. In fact the argument I give seems to give that $\int_{\mathbb{R} }f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x<\infty$, which probably means I've done something wrong.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it is possible to construct a function $f$, which has two singularities, one in $[a,b]$ and one not in $[a,b]$. Integrating over both singularities would yield a finite result (eliminating each other) but only integrating over one singularity results in a divergent integral.

Comment: The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\left|\left(x-3\right)\right|}-\frac{1}{\left|\left(x+3\right)\right|}$ has 2 singularities ([as you can see here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oa78slh0dv)), but its integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, "does not converge" [as per wolfral alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cleft%7C%5Cleft%28x-3%5Cright%29%5Cright%7C%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cleft%7C%5Cleft%28x%2B3%5Cright%29%5Cright%7C%7D+%29+from+infinity+to+-infinity)

Comment: Suppose $f$ is nonnegative for starters.  If $A \subseteq B \subseteq\mathbb{R}$ it is easy to show that $\int_A f \leqslant \int_B f$.  You really have to be more precise about what you mean by $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f$, particularly when $f(x)$ can change sign.

Comment: @VentsiRadev I'm not saying that such a construction holds for all functions which have two singularities.

Comment: Clearly for the Lebesgue integral and $f$ nonnegative we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f < +\infty  \implies \int_a^b f < +\infty$.

Comment: @vitamind Could you try to construct such a function (over the reals) for which the integral is finite? Because I think the integral of any function involving at least one singularity over the range of the singularity/singularities is undefined.

Comment: @RRL Regarding your first comment: I took that notation from the person who commented and deleted their comment. I assumed that $\int_{\mathbb{R} }f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x<\infty$ is equivalent to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ and hence used the two interchangeably. Feel free to replace the former by the latter anywhere you see it. 

Regarding your second comment: I agree, but I don't think it's quite so obvious for the case when we allow $f$ to be negative, and that is the case in which I am most interested.

Comment: This discussion could go on forever without an agreed definition of the integral. Riemann improper integral? Lebesgue integral? Make it clear please.

Comment: @zhw. I am not too sure of the distinction to be honest. The context in which I am using the integral is the computation for expectation, which [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Absolutely_continuous_case) is a Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Lebesgue integral.

In general, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f < \infty$ does mean that the integral is finite. For example, we could have $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f = - \infty$. Suppose, however,  we are given $$\tag{*}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f \neq \pm \infty$$

By definition, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^+ -\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^ -$, where $f^+(x) = \max(f(x),0)$ and $f^-(x) = \max(-f(x),0).$

In view of (*) we must have $0 \leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^+ < +\infty$ and $0 \leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^- < +\infty$.  Since $f^+$ and $f^-$ are nonnegative it follows that for any $-\infty <a < b < +\infty$, that

$$0 \leqslant \int_{[a,b]}f^+ \leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^+ < +\infty, \\ 0 \leqslant \int_{[a,b]}f^- \leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^- < +\infty$$

Hence,

$$\int_{[a,b]}f = \int_{[a,b]}f^+- \int_{[a,b]}f^- \neq \pm \infty$$